# PHP Regex: Searching articles for both English and Arabic text

Tags: php, regex, search, arabic

[**Code sample**](http://pastebin.com/4sVYaTS0)

I'm searching articles for keywords which are in both English and Arabic.
The articles can be either in English or Arabic.

My current code is:

```
$k = implode("|", $keywords);
$regexp = "/(?i)\b(".$k.")\b/";
preg_match_all( $regexp, $content, $matches );
```

But this doesn't find keywords in Arabic articles for some reason. I've verified that both the keywords and articles are being read correctly; no encoding issues.

What can I do to fix this? Note that there is no way for me to detect whether an article or keyword is in English or Arabic, so there has to be a single regex to match them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex might simply lack the `/u`nicode flag:

```
$regexp = "/(?i)\b(".$k.")\b/u";
```

Otherwise PCRE has to compare bytes. In that case it might still be able to find the words (when the UTF-8 encoding is identical), but won't ever detect the word `\b`oundaries.

**Update**
Okay `\b` really only detects `\w` boundaries (so depends on the locale setting instead of /u flag). Then try this instead, which uses assertions:

```
$regexp = "/(?<!\p{L})(".$k.")(?!\p{L})/ui";
```

Comment: Just tested. Word boundaries do not work for Arabic. **Edit:** Well that explains it: http://www.mail-archive.com/pcre-dev@exim.org/msg00110.html

Comment: Most excellent! That makes perfect sense. Thanks for the link!